# How to create a project subtype

Tags: visual-studio-2012, reporting-services, visual-studio-extensions

I came across an article in MSDN that talks about [Project Subtypes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166488(v=vs.110).aspx). It gave me an idea for a useful way to extend an existing project type, but I don't see anything that actually walks through the steps of creating a new subtype (is there a tool to get started, what classes do you need, how do you register it with Visual Studio, etc).

What little information I'm seeing is also leading me to believe that this extensibility point is really only used for code projects. I'm looking to extend the SSRS project type (available in BIDS or SSDT). Does anyone know if this is possible?

Any help would be appreciated.